# How to make react-gsap responsive?

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm working on a project with `react-gsap` and `scrollTrigger` and it needs to be responsive.

Please find the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-field-kkg1ys?file=/src/App.js) for your reference.
In the example, I would like the blue block to always be `100vw`. But it seems that the width is fixed at the first render.

I had to add a `key` and update the `key` on resize, to make the element re-mount.
But it's not working well sometimes, for example, the pinned element goes to wrong position.

I think you can reproduce the issue by checking the DevTools device mode and rotate it.
[image]

I was wondering why the 'adding key' solution fails?
And is there any way to solve it?
or better way to make it responsive?